# Winsock, command line on a remote server

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm new with winsock, i work in linux enviroment, I am trying to write a program where the client will connect on a shell server, I am having trouble sending output to client, I have not develope the full client yet, I'm using netcat for testing,
but do not get the data in the output...
someone can give help to improve this code?

what should I do so that the client receives the output of cmd command ?

```
int Socket_Manip::SHELL() {

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    memset((void *)&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    memset((void *)&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));

    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.hStdInput = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;
    si.hStdOutput = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;
    si.hStdError = (HANDLE)ClientSocket;
    CreateProcess(NULL,"cmd", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stop using C-style casts, they merely hide errors that the compiler could catch. Further, your problem description is almost useless, no error message, no expected output, no minimal example. I also guess you are trying to achieve too many things at once, but that's hard to tell.

Comment: You should explain why you speak of Linux environment and netcat on one part (fine is Linux), and of winsock showing the creation of a `cmd.exe` sub process on Windows ? What are you exactly trying to do with this code ? BTW if it was the question, the call to CreateProcess wants initialized si and pi structures. But please precise your question.

Comment: I just want to know, what should I do so that the client receives the output of cmd command

Comment: Offtopic: `memset` can be written in this way: `memset( &si, 0, sizeof si )`. First parameter is of `void *` type to skip type casting - the real pointer must be `uint8_t *` because length is in bytes. `sizeof` requires brackets only when used with type (not variable).

Comment: Winsock doesn't exist in the Linux environment, unless you are using some unnamed emulator, and it doesn't have a command line either. Please revise yor title and question so it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a socket to redirect `CreateProcess()` I/O.  Use pipes from `CreatePipe()` instead.  Refer to MSND for an example:

[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx)

You will have to write some monitoring code that passes data back and forth between the pipes and socket as needed.  Try something like this:

```
struct sThreadInfo
{
    SOCKET Socket;
    HANDLE hStdIn;
    HANDLE hStdOut;
    bool Stop;
};

DWORD WINAPI ClientSocketToShell(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    sThreadInfo *ti = (sThreadInfo*) lpParameter;

    BYTE buffer[1024];
    DWORD BytesWritten;
    fd_set rds;

    while (!ti->Stop)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rds);
        FD_SET(ti->Socket, &rds);

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int ret = select(0, &rds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;

        if (ret > 0)
        {
            ret = recv(ti->Socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            if (ret <= 0)
                break;

            if (!WriteFile(ti->hStdIn, buffer, ret, &BytesWritten, NULL))
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD WINAPI ShellToClientSocket(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    sThreadInfo *ti = (sThreadInfo*) lpParameter;

    BYTE buffer[1024];
    DWORD BytesAvailable, BytesRead;

    while (!ti->Stop)
    {
        if (!PeekNamedPipe(ti->hStdOut, NULL, 0, NULL, &BytesAvailable, NULL))
            break;

        if (BytesAvailable != 0)
        {
            if (!ReadFile(ti->hStdOut, buffer, min(sizeof(buffer), BytesAvailable), &BytesRead, NULL))
                break;

            ret = send(ti->Socket, buffer, BytesRead, 0);
            if (ret <= 0)
                break;
        }
        else
            Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}

int Socket_Manip::SHELL()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr; 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

    HANDLE hStdIn_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdIn_Wr = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdOut_Rd = NULL;
    HANDLE hStdOut_Wr = NULL;

    if (!CreatePipe(&hStdOut_Rd, &hStdOut_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
        return 0;
    SetHandleInformation(hStdOut_Rd, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    if (!CreatePipe(&hStdIn_Rd, &hStdIn_Wr, &saAttr, 0))
    {
        CloseHandle(hStdOut_Rd);
        CloseHandle(hStdOut_Wr);
        return 0;
    }
    SetHandleInformation(hStdIn_Wr, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0);

    STARTUPINFO si;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.hStdError = hStdOut_Wr;
    si.hStdOutput = hStdOut_Wr;
    si.hStdInput = hStdIn_Rd;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    TCHAR cmd[] = TEXT("cmd");
    if (CreateProcess(NULL, cmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);

        sThreadInfo ti;
        ZeroMemory(&ti, sizeof(ti));
        ti.Socket = ClientSocket;
        ti.hStdIn = hStdIn_Wr;
        ti.hStdOut = hStdOut_Rd;
        ti.Stop - false;

        HANDLE Handles[3];
        DWORD dwThreadID;

        ZeroMemory(Handles, sizeof(Handles));
        Handles[0] = pi.hProcess;
        Handles[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ClientSocketToShell, &ti, 0, &dwThreadID);
        Handles[2] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &ShellToClientSocket, &ti, 0, &dwThreadID);

        DWORD ret = WaitForMultipleObjects(3, Handles, FALSE, INFINITE);

        ti.Stop = true;
        if (ret != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);

        WaitForMultipleObjects(2, &Handles[1], TRUE, INFINITE);

        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(Handles[1]);
        CloseHandle(Handles[2]);
   }

    CloseHandle(hStdIn_Rd);
    CloseHandle(hStdIn_Wr);
    CloseHandle(hStdOut_Rd);
    CloseHandle(hStdOut_Wr);

    return 0;
}
```